# Eclipse Web Service: how to get current path

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, apache-axis

Sure this question has been asked some times already. Still, I don't get the right answer until now.

Using Eclipse, I did the following steps:

1. Create `Dynamic Web Project`
2. Implement my service class
3. Create new Web Service

It all works and the service more or less starts. Apparently, a WSDL (which I will use later) is generated as well.

In the constructor of my service implementation, I'm desperately trying to read a custom file - which resides in `WebContent`

I'm not very experienced at creating web services. But I'm using Tomcat 7, Axis 2 and some JPA. In any case, I cannot access the `ServletContext` class. I'm not implementing my own servlet either.

I tried all of these:

## 1

```
`new File(".").getAbsolutePath()`
```

--> returns my own home directory.

## 2

```
@Resource
private WebServiceContext context;
....
ServletContext servletContext =
(ServletContext) context.getMessageContext().get(MessageContext.SERVLET_CONTEXT);
```

--> `context` is always null. I found somewhere, that this is only injected after calling a first service method. Not really my solution.

## 3

Don't have the code handy anymore, I used some snippet with NIO. Gotta find it... Didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to read a file in the service, you can place it in the package and access as a resource.

```
InputStream is = className.class.getResourceAsStream("filename.xml");
```